# Can A PDF File Be Rendered in Python Without Native Code Libraries?

Tags: python, pdf

I know that PDF files can be viewed using Poppler and various combinations of software and programming languages, such as using Qt 4 or 5 and C or C++.

I've also seen ways to display PDFs from Python using GTK or other libraries that need to be installed on a system.  I know to do any direct display, I'll have to use that.

I do not want to create PDF files.  I want to be able to take a PDF file and render it, one page at a time, into a graphical format and then display the result of that page.

Is there any way to be able to render a PDF to a graphical format, like JPG, PNG, or BMP without requiring libraries that are likely in native code on whatever system is being used?  For instance Poppler is in either C or C++ (I keep forgetting which) and is compiled and installed as binary libraries.

Some background that may help is that I saw a link to [Kivy](http://kivy.org/#home), which would be an easy to use cross-platform GUI toolkit for Python, but I'd need to display PDFs for some projects.  I don't mind doing the extra step of having to render it, then displaying the output if it gives me more independence from needing other libraries.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but the answer is simply going to be no. PDF rendering is difficult, and not that many libraries do it well enough to be usable.

Comment: So, in one way or another, I'd have to go with Poppler or GTK, then?